# can this python be shorter

Tags: python, django

I tend to obsess about expressing code the most compactly and succinctly possible without sacrificing runtime efficiency.

Here's my code:

```
p_audio = plate.parts.filter(content__iendswith=".mp3") 
p_video = not p_audio and plate.parts.filter(content__iendswith=".flv") 
p_swf =   not p_audio and not p_video and plate.parts.filter(content__iendswith=".swf") 
extra_context.update({
  'p_audio':  p_audio and p_audio[0],
  'p_video':  p_video and p_video[0],
  'p_swf':    p_swf and   p_swf[0]
})
```

Are there any python/django gurus that can drastically shorten this code?

Comment: 1. Take question title out of programming context; 2. Picture it in your head; 3. Flinch.

Comment: AS far as the code, I wish there was a shorthand for making extra-context entries with the same name as their values, as that is extremely common.  But you constantly see this name duplication in Django code.

Comment: "compact" and "succinct" aren't nearly as important as "semantic" and "readable". I like my code to be as refined as possible as well, but I choose to be more verbose when doing so will enhance understanding. Using `and` to get the first item of the queryset if it exists, is certainly "compact", but doesn't clearly indicate what's happening at a glance.

Comment: Python books always mention the "and/or" trick (which the above is a variation of).  The whole point of that is compactness.

Comment: But anyway, I think its too long as it is above, was hoping someone could shorten it.

Comment: What values should appear in the dict when the content is not found? It looks like you currently end up with `[]`; would any false-ish value suffice?

Comment: @Mark: I think you missed my point. Making your code as compact as possible without an eye towards readability is the CompSci-equivalent of masturbation -- it serves no purpose but making you feel good.

Comment: Karl Knechtel - yes any falsish value would do, as long as it evaluates to false in the template.  But actually, its actual false that's being returned here.

Comment: Chris Pratt, this is all getting very philosphical, but for example Ernest Hemingway tended to write extremely short novels.  The Old Man and the Sea which he won the pulitzer for is under 100 pages I think.  His brevity came from working in newspapers, but I think prose writers are always looking to drastically edit and pare down their text, unless their wordy hacks.  In general it seems like a lot of programmers get some sort of satisfaction out of line count, as long as your talking about masterbation.

Comment: But as far as why I wrote short code, if its short enough, it convinces me or gives the appearance of not doing something outlandish.  Everyone can see some long conditonal monstrosity and think, that's ugly it needs to be refactored.  Well, anything short gives the appearance of reasonableness at least to me.

Comment: True, it does boil down to philosophy, and the `and` stuff was just an example, and not held up as a never, ever do this thing, but still, I've had the privilege(?) of working with a lot of pre-existing code, and have developed a very pointed view of readability as a result. While very refined code is often less verbose and more compact, yes, that doesn't then mean compact code is *refined* code. The goal of programming, IMHO is to express meaning succinctly, but the first part is most important. Make your code meaningful, then make it succinct in so much as the readability is not affected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides featuring less redundancy, this is also way easier to extend with new content types.

```
kinds = (("p_audio", ".mp3"), ("p_video", ".flv"), ("p_swf", ".swf"))
extra_context.update((key, False) for key, _ in kinds)

for key, ext in kinds:
    entries = plate.parts.filter(content__iendswith=ext)
    if entries:
        extra_context[key] = entries[0]
        break
```

Comment: There's no reason I couldn't use mp3 itself as a key (instead of "p_audio") etc.

Comment: so maybe, kinds = ["mp3", "flv", "swf"]
extra_context.update((key, False) for key in kinds)

for key in kinds:
    entries = plate.parts.filter(content__iendswith=key)
    if entries:
        extra_context[key] = entries[0]
        break

Comment: And also add that slice [:1] to the end of the filter as suggested by Daniel Roseman

Answer (score 3):

Actually, in your pursuit of compactness and efficiency, you have managed to come up with code that is terribly inefficient. This is because when you refer to `p_audio` or `not p_audio`, that causes that queryset to be evaluated - and because you haven't sliced it before then, that means that the entire filter is brought from the database - eg all the `plate` objects that end with mp3, and so on.

You should ensure you do the slice for each query first, before you refer to the value of that query. Since you're concerned with code compactness, you probably want to slice with `[:1]` first, to get a queryset of a single object:

```
p_audio = plate.parts.filter(content__iendswith=".mp3")[:1]
p_video = not p_audio and plate.parts.filter(content__iendswith=".flv") [:1]
p_swf =   not p_audio and not p_video and plate.parts.filter(content__iendswith=".swf")[:1]
```

and the rest can stay the same.

**Edit to add** Because you're only interested in the first element of each list, as evidenced by the fact that you only pass `[0]` from each element into the context. But in your code, `not p_audio` refers to the original, unsliced queryset: and to determine the true/false value of the qs, Django has to evaluate it, which gets all matching elements from the database and converts them into Python objects. Since you don't actually want those objects, you're doing a lot more work than you need.

Note though that it's not re-running it *every* time: just the first time, since after the first evaluation the queryset is cached internally. But as I say, that's already more work than you want.

Comment: You seem to be saying that p_audio is rerunning the query itself each time I subsequently refer to p_audio for example.  I thought that filter is returning a list.  Why do I need to slice it to make it an actual list

Comment: `filter` returns a `QuerySet`, which functions *like* a list, but is *not* a list. Namely, `QuerySet`s are "lazy", they do just-in-time hits to the DB to get their values, which means you can chain filters and still have only one query, but it also means that if you use it improperly, you can end up multiplying your DB queries.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding this as another answer inspired by Pyroscope's above (as my edit there has to be peer reviewed)

The latest incarnation is exploiting that the Django template system just disregards nonexistant context items when they are referenced, so mp3, etc below do not need to be initialized to False (or 0).  So, the following meets all the functionality of the code from the OP.  The other optimization is that mp3, etc are used as key names (instead of "p_audio" etc.)

```
for key in ['mp3','flv','swf'] :
  entries = plate.parts.filter(content__iendswith=key)[:1]
  extra_context[key] = entries and entries[0]
  if extra_context[key] :
     break
```